# Cisco Aironet 2800i Mobility-Express missing option for conversion

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands, access-point

I hope this is an easy one. I'm scractching my head as there are 10-20 articles on how to convert from a capwap firmware to mobilty express for 2800/3800 all using the command:
ap-type mobilty-express tftp://x.x.x.x/firmware-ME.tar

Issue is I don't have that option on this 2802i? The only option I have are 'capwap' or 'workgroup-bridge'?

show version:

```
#show version
             Restricted Rights Legend

Use, duplication, or disclosure by the Government is subject to
restrictions as set forth in subparagraph (c) of the Commercial
Computer Software - Restricted Rights clause at FAR sec. 52.227-19 and
subparagraph (c) (1) (ii) of the Rights in Technical Data and Computer
Software clause at DFARS sec. 252.227-7013.

            Cisco Systems, Inc.
            170 West Tasman Drive
            San Jose, California 95134-1706

This product contains cryptographic features and is subject to United
States and local country laws governing import, export, transfer and
use. Delivery of Cisco cryptographic products does not imply
third-party authority to import, export, distribute or use encryption.
Importers, exporters, distributors and users are responsible for
compliance with U.S. and local country laws. By using this product you
agree to comply with applicable laws and regulations. If you are unable
to comply with U.S. and local laws, return this product immediately.

A summary of U.S. laws governing Cisco cryptographic products may be found at:
http://www.cisco.com/wwl/export/crypto/tool/stqrg.html

If you require further assistance please contact us by sending email to
export@cisco.com.

This product contains some software licensed under the
"GNU General Public License, version 2" provided with
ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY under the terms of
"GNU General Public License, version 2", available here:
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html

This product contains some software licensed under the
"GNU Library General Public License, version 2" provided
with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY under the terms of "GNU Library
General Public License, version 2", available here:
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.0.html

This product contains some software licensed under the
"GNU Lesser General Public License, version 2.1" provided
with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY under the terms of "GNU Lesser
General Public License, version 2.1", available here:
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.html

This product contains some software licensed under the
"GNU General Public License, version 3" provided with
ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY under the terms of
"GNU General Public License, Version 3", available here:
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html.

This product contains some software licensed under the
"GNU Affero General Public License, version 3" provided
with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY under the terms of
"GNU Affero General Public License, version 3", available here:
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html.

Cisco AP Software, (ap3g3), C2802, RELEASE SOFTWARE
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2023 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Tue Jul 11 07:07:26 GMT 2023

ROM: Bootstrap program is U-Boot boot loader
BOOTLDR: U-Boot boot loader Version 2013.01-ge45440da4 (Jun 22 2023 - 10:47:24)

APCC16.7EDE.AD56 uptime is 0 days, 0 hours, 3 minutes
Last reload time   : Tue Jul 11 08:06:02 UTC 2023
Last reload reason : Capwap Discovery Failed

cisco AIR-AP2802I-B-K9 ARMv7 Processor rev 1 (v7l) with 1028192/592856K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID FDW2048B1N1
AP Running Image     : 17.9.4.27
Primary Boot Image   : 17.9.4.27
Backup Boot Image    : 17.2.1.15
Primary Boot Image Hash:
Backup  Boot Image Hash: 7fc0a0901cf96b7c5cb05490efab38bd087a739a189d7c078321a91d02afdd469b173c9219736c2c5bd646b5527c9c603d950249218bbbaa92e48dfbccb3aff5
2 Gigabit Ethernet interfaces
2 802.11 Radios
Radio Driver version : 9.0.5.5-W8964
Radio FW version : 9.1.8.1
NSS FW version : 2.4.30

Base ethernet MAC Address            : CC:16:7E:DE:AD:56
Part Number                          : 73-100821-03
PCA Assembly Number                  : 000-00000-00
PCA Revision Number                  :
PCB Serial Number                    : FDO204816PK
Top Assembly Part Number             : 068-100738-01
Top Assembly Serial Number           : FDW2048B1N1
Top Revision Number                  : A0
Product/Model Number                 : AIR-AP2802I-B-K9
```

show inventory:

```
#show inventory
NAME: AP2800, DESCR: Cisco Aironet 2800 Series (IEEE 802.11ac) Access Point
PID: AIR-AP2802I-B-K9 , VID: V01, SN: FDW2
```

show flash:

```
#show flash
Directory of /storage/
total 140K
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             2 Jul 11 08:06 BOOT_COUNT
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             2 Jul 11 08:06 BOOT_COUNT.reserve
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            29 Jul 11 08:06 RELOADED_AT_UTC
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         39741 Jul 11 07:23 after-upgrade.log
drwxr-xr-x    2 rsyncuse root           160 Jul 11 08:07 application
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           573 Jul 11 08:05 base_capwap_cfg_info
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         35843 Jul 11 07:23 before-upgrade.log
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             2 Nov 28  2016 boot_debug
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 28  2016 bootloader.log
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             5 Jul 11 07:07 bootloader_verify.shadow
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            18 Nov 28  2016 config
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Jul 11 08:06 config.local
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            17 Jul 11 08:07 config.mobexp
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Jul 11 08:07 config.oeap
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            26 Jul 11 07:11 config.wireless
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root           160 Jan  1  1970 cores
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           213 Jul 11 07:22 last_good_uplink_config
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root           160 Jan  1  1970 lists
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            63 Nov 28  2016 part1_info.ver
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           219 Jul 11 07:23 part2_info.ver
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root           448 Jul 11 07:44 pnp
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Jul 11 08:06 random_seed
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             3 Nov 28  2016 rxtx_mode
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 28  2016 sensord_CSPRNG0
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 28  2016 sensord_CSPRNG1
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root           648 Nov 28  2016 ssh
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            40 Nov 28  2016 stable_secret_seed
drwxr-xr-x    3 support  root           224 Nov 28  2016 support
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          3504 Jul 11 08:07 syslogs
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             1 Jul 11 08:07 wips_adminstate_capwap
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
flash                    58.8M    388.0K     55.4M   1% /storage
```

Comment: You do not detail versions, and that is important. Please edit the question to include the AP software version you have and the AP software bundle you want to use. There are specific requirements for which version you have and which bundle you need.

Comment: Also, _never_ use an image for text. Please just copy the text and paste it in using the Prefomatted Text option (right next to the image option you used.

Comment: Did you perform the prerequisite, "_Ensure that you remove the priming configuration in the AP by using the `capwap ap erase all` command_," before trying to upgrade?

Comment: @RonMaupin yes, I ran capwap ap erase all. Loging Cisco/Cisco.